# Run jena with pellet

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jena, semantic-web, pellet

I'm newbie in java and semantic world (coming from PHP world) . I'm going to run jena with pellet reasoner . my IDE is Intellij , and i have downloaded [Pellet package](https://github.com/Complexible/pellet) as well as [jena package](https://jena.apache.org/download/index.cgi), pellet contains folders such as owl and jena .
i dont know if i should import jar files from both of these packages and then start codding or everything needed is already in pellet package ? in fact i need a step  by step tutorial but i cant find one.

Answer (score 1):

If you're managing your dependencies with Maven or equivalent, you only need the Pellet dependency added to your project and all other dependencies will be imported for you. If you're not, you'll need all jars added to your classpath - warning: it's a lot of them.

Regarding tutorials, have you checked out the Apache Jena website? It has a lot of documentation on how to use `OntModel` instances.